# How to read knitr/Rmd cache in interactive session?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have an `Rmd` file with a lot of cached code chunks.

Now I want to keep developing that script using an interactive session to play around and test different solutions before putting the final code in a new chunk of the document.

With a plain `R` script, I could just source it to get my interactive session  on par with the last line of the script.
However, this would result in (re-)executing all code within the interactive session.

I want to read my `Rmd` file into an interactive session ignoring the Markdown part & making use of the existing `knitr` cache, ideally without creating any output.

How can I do this?

PS: I am not looking for some IDE-specific way to set this up but for a command that I can run from a simple R session in any terminal emulator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I *think* that running `library("knitr"); knit("foo.Rmd")` in the console/R session is the easiest way to do this, although it will rewrite `foo.md`, figures, etc.. (Too busy/lazy to test it at the moment.)

You could probably poke around in the `cache` directory and read the cached files directly, but that would be a lot more work/trickier.

Comment: I really want to avoid re-writing the Markdown file, since I might have a Makefile depending on that one.  I was hoping for something like your second suggestion but in an automated way in order (I guess one has to parse the Rmd, identify code chunks, hash them, check for a matching cache, load the data if possible or run the code skipping print & plot statements otherwise. If there really is no function doing this or something similar, I would be fine writing it since I'd use it over and over. Most importantly the cache can depend on (also cached) parameters unknown at the time of reading it.

Comment: @mschilli could you supply /dev/null (or a file you don't care about) to the `output` parameter?

Comment: @NickK: I could and this would work if the cache was produced by `Rscript -e 'library("knitr");knit("foo.Rmd")'` in the first place. It was however produced by `Rscript -e 'library("knitr");bar<-"X";knit("foo.Rmd")'` and `X` is unknown at the time of loading the cache. That's one of the reasons I want to use the cache: Not only will it save time by not re-computing everything, but also will the cache contain the value assigned to `bar` when `knit`ing `foo.Rmd`.

Comment: actually I just spen quite some effort produce a MWE to show why that solution wouldn't work just to be surprised to find out it actually does. `knitr` is intelligent to overwrite parameters with cached values as soon as it reached the first cached chunk modifiying this parameter. So running `Rscript -e 'library("knitr");knit("foo.Rmd",out="/dev/null");bar'` will actually print `"X"`.

Answer (score 14):

I've created functions load the objects from cached chunks into an interactive R session.  The functions are `lazyload_cache_dir` and `lazyload_cache_labels` and are available in [qwraps2](https://github.com/dewittpe/qwraps2) version > 0.2.4

A detailed example of the use of these functions is
[here:](http://www.peteredewitt.com/2017/lazyloading-cached-chunks/)

Quick overview:

Say you have the file `report.Rmd`

````
---
title:  "A Report"
output: html_document
---

```{r first-chunk, cache = TRUE}
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars)
x <- pi
```

```{r second-chunk, cache = TRUE}
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + am, data = mtcars)
xx <- exp(1)
```
````

After knitting you end up with a this project directory

```
.
├── report_cache
│   └── html
│       ├── first-chunk_bf368425c25f0c3d95cac85aff007ad1.RData
│       ├── first-chunk_bf368425c25f0c3d95cac85aff007ad1.rdb
│       ├── first-chunk_bf368425c25f0c3d95cac85aff007ad1.rdx
│       ├── __packages
│       ├── second-chunk_2c7d6b477306be1d4d4ed451f2f1b52a.RData
│       ├── second-chunk_2c7d6b477306be1d4d4ed451f2f1b52a.rdb
│       └── second-chunk_2c7d6b477306be1d4d4ed451f2f1b52a.rdx
├── report.html
└── report.Rmd
```

and you want to load the objects from `first-chunk`.

```
lazyload_cache_labels("first-chunk", path = "report_cache/html")
## Lazyloading report_cache/html/first-chunk_bf368425c25f0c3d95cac85aff007ad1
ls()
## [1] "fit" "x"
```

See [the blog post](http://www.peteredewitt.com/2017/lazyloading-cached-chunks/) for details on loading only a whole directory of cached objects or loading specific objects from within a cached chunk.

Answer (score 12):

Internally, [knitr uses `lazyLoad`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/db496a720b3f79fe507fd3900730869af48639d7/R/cache.R#L59) to load cached results, and so can you:

```
lazyLoad('knitr_cache_dir/chunk_2c7d6b477306be1d4d4ed451f2f1b52a')
```

Make sure to supply the filename without the suffix.